# Delay when rendering svg image in react application

Tags: reactjs, image, svg

I am using React version 16.8.6. I am trying to load some SVG images in my application, But there is a 1-second delay before the image appears in dom.

Here is how I load svg image

```
import menuIcon from 'public/images/menu_icon.svg';
<img src={menuIcon} />
```

Please find the gif link that shows the loading delay issue. 
https://ibb.co/jH35S38

PS. This happens in production only.

Comment: depends what's in the menu_icon.svg If it's large enough it may take 1 second to a) transfer over your network and b) render.

Comment: Sorry, Edited my question. It happens only in production and the SVG images are not that big it's 2 kb each(without gzip)

Comment: We're going to need a testcase here. We don't debug production systems. Once you fix your production system, your question isn't helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem, i found the article below which says that you can use SVGs as component and because the image is not loaded as a separate file there is no delay.
It works for me.

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/

```
import React from 'react';

import {ReactComponent as ReactLogo} from './logo.svg';

const App = () => {
return (
 <div className="App">
   <ReactLogo />
 </div>
);
}
export default App;
```